# python pandas wildcard? Replace all values in df with a constant

Tags: python, pandas, wildcard

I have a `df` and want to make a `new_df` of the same size but with all `1`s. Something to the spirit of: `new_df=df.replace("*","1")`. I think this is faster than creating a new df from scratch, because i would need to get the dimensions, fill it with `1`s, and copy all the headers over. Unless I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(df.shape), columns=df.columns)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = [
    [1,1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2,2],
    [3,3,3,3,3],
    [4,4,4,4,4],
    [5,5,5,5,5],
]

cols = ["A","B","C","D","E"]

%timeit df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(df.shape), columns=df.columns)
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.6 µs per loop

%timeit df2 = df.copy(); df2.loc[:, :] = 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 245 µs per loop

%timeit df3 = df * 0 + 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 200 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty easy.

```
import pandas as pd

d = [
    [1,1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2,2],
    [3,3,3,3,3],
    [4,4,4,4,4],
    [5,5,5,5,5],
]

cols = ["A","B","C","D","E"]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=cols)
print df

print "------------------------"

df.loc[:,:] = 1
print df
```

Result:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4  4
4  5  5  5  5  5
------------------------
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1
3  1  1  1  1  1
4  1  1  1  1  1
```

Obviously, `df.loc[:,:]` means you target all rows across all columns. Just use `df2 = df.copy()` or something if you want a new dataframe.